# how to use XLMRoberta in fine-tuning ,

Tags: python, nlp

There are two problems i met when i fine-tuning my code.
And i was trying to use X_1 and X_2 to regress.
There are different languages in the corpus.

```
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://huggingface.co/xlm-roberta-base/resolve/main/tf_model.h5

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/2123064688.py in <module>
     55 # )
     56 
---> 57 model = TFXLMRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('xlm-roberta-base',num_labels=1)

OSError: Can't load weights for 'xlm-roberta-base'. Make sure that:

- 'xlm-roberta-base' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'
  (make sure 'xlm-roberta-base' is not a path to a local directory with something else, in that case)

- or 'xlm-roberta-base' is the correct path to a directory containing a file named one of tf_model.h5, pytorch_model.bin.
```

This is my code:

```
tokenizer = XLMRobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('xlm-roberta-base')

train_encoding = tokenizer(X_train_1,X_train_2,truncation=True,padding=True)
val_encoding = tokenizer(X_val_1,X_val_2,truncation=True,padding=True)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (dict(train_encoding),y_train)
)
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (dict(val_encoding),y_val)
)

model = TFXLMRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('xlm-roberta-base',num_labels=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you're better to know before diving deep into `huggingface` transformers.

1. The preferred library for working with `huggingface`'s transformers is `PyTorch`.
2. For several widely used models, you may find the `Tensorflow` version alongside but not for all.
3. fortunately, there are ways to convert `pt` checkpoints to `tf` and vise versa.

Finally how to fix the code:

```
# switching to pytorch
tokenizer = XLMRobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('xlm-roberta-base')
model = XLMRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('xlm-roberta-base')
# using un-official checkpoints
model = TFXLMRobertaForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('jplu/tf-xlm-roberta-base',num_labels=1)
# converting pt checkpoint to tensorflow (not recommended!)
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll try pt later